# In pandas groupby mode use user defined function, apply it to multiple columns and assign the results to new pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following data set:

```
> dt
   a b group
1: 1 5     a
2: 2 6     a
3: 3 7     b
4: 4 8     b
```

I have a following function:

```
def bigSum(a,b):
   return(a.min() + b.max())
```

I want to apply this function to a and b columns in groupby mode (by group) and assign it to the new column c of the data frame. My wished result is

```
    > dt
   a b group  c
1: 1 5     a  7
2: 2 6     a  7
3: 3 7     b  11
4: 4 8     b  11
```

For instance, if I would have used R data.table, I would do the following:

```
dt[, c := bigSum(a,b), by = group]
```

and it would work exactly as I expect. I am interested if there is something similar in pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `pandas` we have `transform`

```
g = df.groupby('group')
df['out'] = g.a.transform('min') + g.b.transform('max')
df
Out[282]: 
   a  b group  out
1  1  5     a    7
2  2  6     a    7
3  3  7     b   11
4  4  8     b   11
```

Update

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x : bigSum(x['a'],x['b'])).reindex(df.group).values
df
Out[287]: 
   a  b group  out  new
1  1  5     a    7    7
2  2  6     a    7    7
3  3  7     b   11   11
4  4  8     b   11   11
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The main point here is, however, to apply exactly my user defined function. In reality my function is a bit more complex and is not easy to split to single functions, like you do here (min + max)